# How can I sense when the client has selected or is in the input?

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to sense when client is in the input tag?  Active doesn't seem to work, it only senses when the mouse click is held down in the input.  I want to style something differently while the client is in the input.

Comment: What do you mean by "sense" specifically? Are you looking for an event handler?

Comment: You're looking for `:focus`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is this

```
input:focus {
    background-color: some color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change style of the text when the user is typing just write css like this`input{font-weight:bold;}` or any style.